# Running multiple pom files from one command

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

So my project has 3 modules but no parent pom file. I can run them manually one by one but I am looking for a way to run all of those 3 pom files using a single mvn command but no luck. So far I have tried few different combination but non of the worked for ex -

```
mvn -f module1/pom.xml -f module2/pom.xml -f module3/pom.xml clean install
```

but it runs only first pom file not all 3 of them. Tried using 'call' too but didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need a `<parent>` project, you need an _aggregator_ (a.k.a. _multi-module_) project. Don't confuse [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Inheritance_v).

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you always want to build those projects together, put them into a multi-module project and build it from the main POM of that project.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the command of each project to execute one after the other:

```
mvn -f module1/pom.xml clean install | mvn -f module2/pom.xml clean install | mvn -f module3/pom.xml clean install
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a specific reason to try and run them in one command? If it comes down that they depend on each other, you could find the `pom` that needs to run first and add something like this

Your first `pom`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
 
  <modules>
    <module>SecondPomFile</module> <---------------
    <module>ThirdPomFile</module> <---------------
  </modules>
</project>
```

The second `pom`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>SecondPomFile</artifactId> <---------------
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

The Third`pom`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>ThirdPomFile</artifactId> <---------------
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

and then run it like `mvn -f pom.xml`

Because you added

```
  <modules>
    <module>SecondPomFile</module> <---------------
    <module>ThirdPomFile</module> <---------------
  </modules>
```

The name you specified then points to the other poms and they run when the first one runs

Comment: Re "_find the pom that needs to run first_" – Module build order is calculated by the [_Maven reactor_](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). The order of `<module>` declarations is only the last of five sorting criteria.